# Delete row by its data-* attr does not work, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML code:

```
<table class="table" id="restricted_component_data">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Component ID</th>
    </tr>  
    <tr data-component-id="15">
      <td>
        <span class="remove_restriction" data-component-id="15">X</span>
      </td>
      <td>link_component_restriction</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-component-id="12">
      <td>
        <span class="remove_restriction" data-component-id="12">X</span>
      </td>
      <td>link_component_restriction 12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-component-id="11">
      <td>
        <span class="remove_restriction" data-component-id="11">X</span>
      </td>
      <td>link_component_restriction 11</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I am trying to delete the `tr` element by its `data-component-id` attr. So this is what I am doing:

```
$(function() {
  $('#restricted_component_data').on('click', '.remove_restriction', function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var component_id = $(this).data('component-id');

    $('#restricted_component_data').find('tr [data-component-id="' + component_id + '"]').remove();
  });
});
```

But my code isn't working since it only deletes the column and not the row (try it on the Fiddle). I am missing something here but I am not sure what it is.

Can any help to find out why this is not working?

There is a Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/e0hy5m7s/) to play with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible, I would do it via traversal, [as shown in Sachin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40893513/157247).

If for some reason you can't do that:

The reason what you have isn't working is you're only matching the `td`, not the `tr`, because your selector is for elements with that attribute that are *within* (descendants of) the `tr`.

Instead of

```
$('#restricted_component_data').find('tr [data-component-id="' + component_id + '"]').remove();
```

you want

```
$('#restricted_component_data').find('tr:has([data-component-id="' + component_id + '"])').remove();
// -------------------------------------^^^^^------------------------------------------^
```

or

```
$('#restricted_component_data').find('tr [data-component-id="' + component_id + '"]').closest('tr').remove();
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

or as [Eun points out in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40893445/delete-row-by-its-data-attr-does-not-work-why/40893483#comment69000891_40893483), since that same data attribute is on the `tr` as well as the `td`, you can just use your original code but with the space after `tr` removed:

```
$('#restricted_component_data').find('tr[data-component-id="' + component_id + '"]').remove();
// No space here -----------------------^
```

Comment: or remove the space between `tr` and `[`: `$('#restricted_component_data').find('tr[data-component-id="' + component_id + '"]').remove();`

Answer (score 3):

you can also do it by this:

```
$(this).closest("tr").remove()
```

you dont need any component id for this.

Comment: This is by far the best way to do it.

Comment: This wont work because I have another piece of code and `this` isn't the element :)

Comment: if this isn't the element then how will this code works? `$(this).data('component-id')`

Comment: @ReynierPM: In the code you've quoted in your question, `this` is definitely referring to the `.remove_restriction` span, which is inside the row you want to remove, and so the above will work just fine.

Comment: @Sachin because this is only part of the code rebuild only for this question but anyway you're right

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes, you're right but I was looking for your answer though

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the space after "tr" in the selector, i.e.

```
'tr [data-component-id="
```

to:

```
'tr[data-component-id="
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e0hy5m7s/1/

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space you have in `find(tr [data-....` to `find(tr[data-....`

Answer (score 0):

Use this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/0zrqcysj/#&togetherjs=doy8RsKtuj)

JS:

```
$(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.remove_restriction', function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var component_id = $(this).data('component-id');

    alert(component_id);

    $(this).closest('tr[data-component-id="' + component_id + '"]').remove();
  });
});
```